# Qt Linear gradient for polygons

Tags: c++, qt

I want to fill the polygons with linear gradient color and am not sure how to implent it. So far am using the following code.

```
std::vector<Element*> elems = m_mesh->getElements();

for (unsigned int i=0; i<elems.size(); ++i)
{
    std::vector<Node*> nodes = elems[i]->getNodes();


    QPolygon elepolygon;
    unsigned int j;
    for (j=0; j<nodes.size(); ++j)
    {
        elepolygon << QPoint(nodes[j]->x()*scalex+shiftx,nodes[j]->y()*scaley+shifty);
    }


    int r = qrand() % ((255 + 1) - 0);
    int g = qrand() % ((255 + 1) - 0);
    int b = qrand() % ((255 + 1) - 0);

    QBrush brush(QColor(r,g,b));

    QPainterPath tmpPath;
    tmpPath.addPolygon(elepolygon);
    painter.fillPath(tmpPath,brush);
    painter.drawPolygon(elepolygon);

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `QLinearGradient`, set the colors at different stop points using `setColorAt` function and set the brush of the painter to the created `QLinearGradient` :

```
    painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3));

    QLinearGradient gradient(-400,-400,400,400);
    gradient.setColorAt(0, QColor(110,110,110));
    gradient.setColorAt(0.27, QColor(230,230,230));
    gradient.setColorAt(0.44, QColor(110,110,110));
    gradient.setColorAt(0.76, QColor(230,230,230));
    gradient.setColorAt(1, QColor(110,110,110));

    painter->setBrush(gradient);

    painter->drawPolygon(elepolygon);
```

In this example the  interpolation area is between (-400,-400) and (400,400). You can have arbitrary ones which define the direction of the gradient.